# callback function after moving some dom elements

Tags: javascript

```
$('#gd').on('click', function(){
    $('.elact').insertBefore($('.elact').prev(), function(){
        console.log('done');  // doesn't work
    });
    $('#bsave').css('visibility', 'visible');  // works
});
```

`insertBefore` also works.

What's the problem with `console.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`insertBefore`](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) doesn't have a callback, because it's not an asynchronous or animation operation. Its work is done as of when the call returns. (CSS animations/transitions may make it seem like it isn't done yet, but from a DOM perspective, it is. If that's what's going on, use [animation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events) handlers or [transition event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_start_and_completion_of_a_transition) handlers.)

For example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    const beforeMe = $("#before-me");
    console.log(
      "Is it there before the move?",
      beforeMe.siblings(".slidein").length > 0 ? "Yes" : "No"
    );
    $(".slidein")
        .insertBefore(beforeMe)
        .on("animationend", function() {
            console.log("Animation complete");
        });
    console.log(
      "Is it there _immediately_ after the move?",
      beforeMe.siblings(".slidein").length > 0 ? "Yes" : "No"
    );

}, 3000);
```

```css
.slidein {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left:100%;
    width:300%
  }
  
  to {
    margin-left:0%;
    width:100%;
  }
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="before-me"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="slidein">I slide</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```